# C++14 decltype(auto) makes CLion highlight as error a valid statement

Tags: c++, c++14, clion

I'm doing some exercises with Scott Meyer's Effective Modern C++ (item 3).

With the following code:

```
template<class T>
class Container
{
  private:
    T _arr[4];

  public:
    T &operator[](std::size_t index)
    {
        return _arr[index];
    }

    explicit Container(T def)
    {
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        {
            _arr[i] = def;
        }
    }
};

template<class C>
decltype(auto) print_and_access4(C&& container, std::size_t index)
{
    std::cout << "Index = " << index << std::endl;
    return container[index];
}
auto& y = print_and_access4(Container<int>(5), 0);
```

Clion complains on the last line:

[image]

So, what's this complaint about?

P.S. Compiling with `g++ --std=c++14 main.cpp` yields no errors or warnings.

```
g++ -v: 
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
```

CLion version:

```
CLion 2017.3.2
```

Comment: There were many constructs which CLion marked as error even though they were not last time I used it...

Comment: @smoothware: Did you start using a different IDE? I'm used to Jetbrains IDEs so I went with it.

Comment: Btw, y is then usable, as dangling reference...

Comment: @Jarod42: Correct, this is not good code. But the expression `print_and_access4(Container<int>(5), 0)` actually is an lvalue.

Comment: I recommend to stay on Clion: there are IDEs that parse C++ correctly, but they lack many Clion features like refactorings and code generators.

Comment: @nakiya I used to really like QtCreator, even under Windows, but it started acting weird and crashing after I closed it. I prefer CLion for CMake based projects though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clion C++ parser currently is not fully standard-compilant. So sometimes it shows errors on valid code, and sometimes shows no errors on invalid code. But it gets better from version to version, so probably it will be fixed soon.

You can report bugs on their tracker:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/CPP

If you want some standard-compliant IDE, you can try IDEs based on Clang, like QtCreator or KDevelop.